# I want print alert message when login failed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print alert message when login failed.when user failed login then i get this URL. what I am trying print alert message when I getting this url. clearly I want print alert message behalf of URL Value.
Any help .

http://example.com/?login=failed&redirect_to=%2Fstarstruckmedia%2F

Comment: Show the code that could result in a failed login.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so please include your attempt(s) in your question. Thank you.

Comment: `if (url.includes('login=failed')) alert('login failed');`

Comment: @trincot if you're going to suggest something like that then I think it would be a good idea to explain how to get the URL as I feel that is the OP's main issue.... not knowing how to get the url. Maybe `window.location.search.includes('login=failed')` if you wish to offer that method.

Comment: OP has not provided that: it might be a response from an ajax call, or an input from a user, or the result of parsing some bigger input provided by an API, ... who knows? Anyway, it was not an answer, just a trigger for more input from OP, otherwise I would have posted an answer. Feel free to answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("login=failed") > -1) {
   alert("login failed");
}
```

Comment: Taioli Francesco@@ can you let me now how to stop redirection  after alert message closed, or how can i stop redirection

Comment: Taioli Francesco@@ @ your    is perfect  solution